# Complete set of equivalence class representative

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let  $\sim$ be a relation on $\mathbb{R}$ and $x\sim y$ if and only if $x-y\in \mathbb{Z}$.

(a) Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation 
(b) Give a complete set of equivalence class representatives.

---

(a) is easy to show, but I really don’t understand (b).

I know that:

$$[a]_{\sim}:=\{y\in \mathbb{R} \mid a\sim y\}$$

so

$$[0]_{\sim}=\{\dots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\dots\}$$

and that

$$\dots=[-2]_{\sim}=[-1]_{\sim}=[0]_{\sim}=[1]_{\sim}=[2]_{\sim}=\,\dots$$

because if $x\sim y$ then $[x]=[y]$.

But how can I find a complete set of equivalence class representatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you find even one other class than $[0]_\sim$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a complete set of equivalence class representatives, I think the question wants a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that for each equivalence class, there is exactly one representative in the set - this is the sense in which it is complete (there is a $1-1$ correspondence between $X$ and $\mathbb{R}/\sim$, the set of equivalence classes).

So what you need to do is for each equivalence class, you need to pick one representative and let $X$ be the set of all your choices. As you point out, there are lots of different representatives you can choose for any given equivalence class. To ensure that your set $X$ contains only one representative for each equivalence class and that each equivalence class does have a representative in $X$, it would be good if you were able to make some sort of consistent choice of representative. For example, there is a reason I would choose $\frac{1}{2}$ to be the element in $X$ which represents $[\frac{5}{2}]_{\sim}$, and I would choose all the other representatives of equivalence classes for the same reason.

Comment: Ok, let $\mathbb{R}/ \sim :=\left\{ \left[0 \right], \left[ \frac{1}{2} \right]_{\sim},\left[\frac{1}{3}\right]_{\sim},\left[\frac{1}{4}\right]_{\sim},.....\right\}$ be the quotient set, then $X=\left\{0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},....\right\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ is the complete set of equivalence class representatives. Is this correct?

Comment: Instead of starting to write a list, you need to be a little bit more specific. For example, I am not sure which representative you would choose for the equivalence class $[\pi]_{\sim}$.

Comment: I know now that we have an equivalence class for each $x \in [0, 1)$, but I have no idea how to write it down.

Comment: What's wrong with writing $[0, 1)$? All you have to do now is explain: 1. why no two elements of $[0, 1)$ are representatives for the same equivalence class; and 2. why each equivalence class has a representative in $[0, 1)$.

Comment: It's getting late in the Netherlands, but I'll give it a try: 1. assume that $x,y \in [0,1)$ and $x \not\sim y$ (proof by contradiction) suppose that $x,y$ are in the same equivalence class, $x,y\in [a]_{\sim}$ then by def. of relation we know that $a\sim x$ and $a \sim y$ we see then that $x\sim y$(symmetric+transitive) which is a contradiction??

Comment: There is a contradiction in there somewhere, but you haven't said what it is. At some point, you are going to need to use the definition of $x \sim y$ to arrive at a contradiction. Just for the record, you don't have to justify the answer to me, I'm just suggesting what you should do. Having said that, I'm happy to discuss your reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* two numbers are equivalent under this relation iff they have the same fractional part.

Comment: so ,correct me if i'm wrong, $\left[ \frac{1}{2} \right]_{\sim}=\left\{ ....,-\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},....\right\}$, but how can I list them all?

Comment: Or can I just say that $\left\{ 0 \right\} \cup \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} |\,0<x<1 \right\}$ is the complete set of equivalence class representatives, because for each x in the set, we can find an equivalence class?

Comment: You can say that.  Is there a shorter way of writing that set?  And then, how would you prove that you've got a complete set of equivalence class representatives?  (You'll need to prove that no two elements of your set are in the same equivalence class, and also that everything in $\Bbb R$ is related to something in the set).